What is the probability that a "happy triangle" contains the centre of its circumcircle? Is it really $1/2$?
On a circle, choose three uniformly random independent points $A,B,C$.
Inside the circle, choose a uniformly random independent point $D$.
Triangle $ABC$ is called "happy" if it contains $D$.

What is the probability that a happy triangle contains the centre of its circumcircle?

Simulations suggest that the probability is $1/2$.
Given the simplicity of this probability, I wonder if there is an intuitive explanation.
Context
This is a variation of the classic question, "What is the probability that a triangle, whose vertices are three random points on a circle, contains the centre of the circle?" The answer to that question is $1/4$, and there is an intuitive explanation.
My attempt
Assume the circle is a unit circle.
From circle triangle picking, the expected area of $\Delta ABC$ is $\dfrac{3}{2\pi}$.
$$\therefore P(\Delta ABC\text{ contains }D)=\dfrac{\frac{3}{2\pi}}{\text{Area of circle}}=\dfrac{3}{2\pi^2}$$
Call the centre of the circle $O$.
$$P\left(\text{$\Delta ABC$ contains $O$ | $\Delta ABC$ contains $D$}\right)$$
$$=\frac{P(\text{$\Delta ABC$ contains $O$ and $D$})}{P(\text{$\Delta ABC$ contains $D$})}$$
$$=\dfrac{2\pi^2}{3}P\left(\text{$\Delta ABC$ contains $O$ and $D$}\right)$$
I do not know how to calculate $P\left(\text{$\Delta ABC$ contains $O$ and $D$}\right)$.
I used this formula to make my simulations.
Possibly related question: "Probability that a random triangle with vertices on a circle contains an arbitrary point inside said circle"
Add this one to the list?
I might add this question to my list of probability questions that have answer $1/2$ but resist intuitive explanation.
Other elegant properties of happy triangles?
Simulations suggest that, for a happy triangle inscribed in a unit circle:

The expected area is $\pi/4$. (Thus, a happy triangle divides the circle into four regions of equal expected area.)
The expected shortest side length is $1$.
The expected product of the three side lengths is $\pi$.
The probability that it contains (another) random point in the circle is $1/4$.
If the sides are, in random order, $a,b,c$, then $P(ab<c)=1/3$. (For not-necessarily-happy $\Delta ABC$, this probability is $1/2$).


There's a trick (originally due to Wendel) to get that "1/4 probability of containing the center": Instead of choosing 3 points from the circle, first choose 3 pairs of opposite points (i.e. three diameters of the circle), then choose one point from each pair.  Your circle fails to contain the center if and only if the 3 points you choose in stage two are consecutive out of the six points you chose in stage one.  This means there's 6 ways to fail to contain the center out of 8, regardless of what happened in stage 1.

It seems (based on some quick geogebra experiments) that there's an "area weighted version of this": For any set of three opposite points chosen in stage 1, the sum of the areas of the possible triangles not containing the center equals the areas of the triangles containing the center.  Since a triangle is happy with probability proportional to its area, this would imply your conjecture.  There may be some quick argument for the "sum of the areas" claim that I'm missing.

You can see the Geogebra calculation at https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/mwtetsce . I assumed WLOG that B was one of the three points chosen.  This leaves four triangles, of which BEC contains the center but BDC, BDF, and BEF do not.

@KevinP.Costello Here is an intuitive proof of the "sum of the areas" claim.

Write $O$ and $D$ as shorthand for the events $O\in\triangle$ and $D\in\triangle$. By Bayes' theorem, $$P(O|D)P(D)=P(D|O)P(O)$$ There is a very simple descsription of $P(D)$: the expected proportional area of the triangle to the circle, $E[|\triangle|/\pi]$. Thus, we have $$P(O|D)E[
|\triangle|]=E[|\triangle||O]P(O)\tag{*}$$ We also know $P(O)=1/4$ by a simple argument. Imagine instead we first picked pairs of antipodal points $\pm A$, $\pm B$, $\pm C$, and then chose the triangle with vertices $(v_1,v_2,v_3)=(\pm A, \pm B, \pm C)$ for an independent choice of signs. There are $8$ possible triangles from this process, but opposite choices of signs give the same triangle $\triangle, -\triangle$ up to inversion, so we only need to consider $4$ choices by choosing representatives. We also know that $O\in\triangle$ exactly when $v_3$ lies in the minor arc between $-v_1$ and $-v_2$. There is only one such triangle among the sign choices for $v_1,v_2$, so WLOG, let this be $\triangle ABC$. We then choose $\triangle A'BC,\triangle AB'C,\triangle ABC'$ as the other three representatives, where $X'$ is shorthand for $-X$. $\triangle ABC$ is the only one containing $O$, so $P(O)=1/4$.

We can use the same ideas to find $E[|\triangle||O]$. In particular, $$|\triangle ABC|=|\triangle A'BC|+|\triangle AB'C|+|\triangle ABC'|\tag{**}$$ This follows from some simple geometry. Let $a,b,c$ be the distances from $O$ to the sides $BC, CA, AB$, respectively. $\triangle AB'C'$ and $\triangle ABC$ share the same base length $\overline{BC}$, but differ in height by $2a$. Thus, $$|\triangle ABC|-|\triangle A'BC|=|\triangle ABC|-|\triangle AB'C'|=a\overline{BC}$$ It follows that $$\begin{align*} 3|\triangle ABC|-|\triangle A'BC|-|\triangle AB'C|-|\triangle ABC'|=a\overline{BC}+b\overline{CA}+c\overline{AB} \\ = 2(|\triangle OBC|+|\triangle OCA|+|\triangle OAB|)  \\ = 2|\triangle ABC| \end{align*}$$ from which $(**)$ follows. 
From $(**)$ it follows immediately that $E[|\triangle||O]=2E[|\triangle|]$. Combining with $P(O)=1/4$ in $(*)$, we get $P(O|D)=1/2$ as desired.

Nice. I offer an alternative proof to your $(**)$ statement.

Here I offer an intuitive proof of the fact that, in the diagram below (in which letters represent areas), $A+B+C+D+E+F=a+b+c+d+e+f$. This fact is used in the solutions found in @Kevin P. Costello's comments to the OP, and @Jacob's answer.

(For this proof, don't think in terms of letters; rather, think in term of the shapes in the diagram. I'm using letters just to communicate the idea.)
We have $A+a=b+c$. This is obvious when you consider the triangle with area $A+a+b+c$.
$\therefore A=b+c-a$
Similarly, we have:
$B=a+f-b$
$C=d+e-c$
$D=c+b-d$
$E=f+a-e$
$F=e+d-f$
Add the equations. On the RHS, each small letter appears twice as positive and once as negative (you don't have to count them; it's obvious from symmetry), so altogether exactly once.
$\therefore A+B+C+D+E+F=a+b+c+d+e+f$.

In the $xy$-plane, let


$A,B,C$ be three points chosen uniformly at random from points on the standard unit circle.$\\[4pt]$
$D$ be a point chosen uniformly at random from points in the interior of the standard unit disk.


and where all choices are mutually independent.

Using the letters "$D$","$O$" in a context dependent way, let


$D$ be the event that the interior of $\Delta ABC$ contains the point $D$.$\\[4pt]$
$O$ be the event that the interior of $\Delta ABC$ contains the point $O=(0,0)$.


Claim:$\;P(O{\,|}D)={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

Proof:


We will make the following assumptions . . .


$A,B,C$ are distinct.$\\[4pt]$
$A,B,C$ are in counterclockwise order.$\\[4pt]$
$A=(1,0)$.


The above assumptions will not affect the values for any of the results obtained below.

Based on these assumptions, we can write
\begin{align*}
B&=(\cos(u),\sin(u))\\[4pt]
C&=(\cos(v),\sin(v))\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where$\;0 < u < v < 2\pi$.

From the Shoelace formula, we get
$$
\text{area}(\Delta ABC)
=
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
\Bigl(
(\sin(u)-\sin(v)-\sin(u)\cos(v)+\sin(v)\cos(u)
\Bigr)
$$
Note that the event $O$ occurs if and only if$\;0 < u < \pi < v < u + \pi$.

It follows that
$
E\Bigl(\text{area}(\Delta ABC)\,{\large{|}}\,O\Bigr)
$
can be expresses as
$$
\frac
{
{\displaystyle{
\;\frac{1}{2}
\int_0^\pi\int_\pi^{u+\pi}
\Bigl(
\sin(u)-\sin(v)-\sin(u)\cos(v)+\sin(v)\cos(u)
\Bigr)
\,dv\;du\;\;
}}
}
{
{\displaystyle{
\int_0^\pi\int_\pi^{u+\pi}
\,dv\;du
}}
}
$$
which evaluates to ${\Large{\frac{3}{\pi}}}$.

Then we get
$$
P(D{\,|}O)
=
\frac
{
\,E\Bigl(\text{area}(\Delta ABC)\,{\large{|}}\,O\Bigr)\;
}
{
\text{area}(\text{the unit disk})
}
=
\frac{3}{\pi^2}
$$
As you've noted, we have


$P(O)={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$ $\\[9pt]$
$P(D)={\large{\frac{3}{2\pi^2}}}$


hence by Bayes' formula, we get
\begin{align*}
P(O{\,|}D)
&=
P(D{\,|}O)
\,{\cdot}
\frac{P(O)}{P(D)}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{3}{\pi^2}
\,{\cdot}
\frac{1}{4}
\,{\cdot}
\frac{2\pi^2}{3}
\\[6pt]
&=
\frac{1}{2}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.
